# cube portfolio safari issue - thumbnails disappear

Tags: macos, safari, macos-catalina

does Cube Portfolio have a Safari bug whereby the gallery thumbnail images disappear whenever a filter is selected, only to re-appear when you mouse over the containing div?

I’m using macOS Catalina and it happens everywhere, even on the developer’s (bmihai) demo galleries.